# How can I get all data if params value is Null otherwise Match data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

1. This is the callback function of get method
2. AccountID getting from params and I want  data  but if AccountID is null than I want to show all data otherwise match data

So Where should I put condition and How?

````
Client.connect(URL,function(err,db){
            if(err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db("TestMigration1");
            let AccountID= req.params.id;
            dbo.collection("Calendar").find(
                {"$and":[{"IsDeleted":false},{"AccountID":AccountID}]}).project(
                {
                    "CalendarID":"$_id",
                    "_id":0,
                    "UserID":1,
                    "AccountID":1,
                    "GmailCalendarID":1,
                    "TimeZone":1,
                    "CreatedDt":1,
                    "LastUpdatedDt":1
                }).toArray(function(error, documents) {
                if (err) throw error;
            
                res.send(documents);
                db.close();
            })
            
             
        }); ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like this.

```
const query = {};
let AccountID= req.params.id;
if(AccountID)
   Object.assign(query, {_id: AccountID});
 dbo.collection("Calendar").find(
                {"$and":[{"IsDeleted":false},{"AccountID":AccountID}]}).project(
                {
                    "CalendarID":"$_id",
                    "_id":0,
                    "UserID":1,
                    "AccountID":1,
                    "GmailCalendarID":1,
                    "TimeZone":1,
                    "CreatedDt":1,
                    "LastUpdatedDt":1
                }).toArray(function(error, documents) {
                if (err) throw error;
            
                res.send(documents);
                db.close();
            })
```